# Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Instead of checking temporary table existence like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE #table;
END;
```

I am using the new `DROP IF EXISTS` technique:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb..#table;
```

It is working perfectly, but if the table do not exists, I am getting the following message.

> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.

Does anyone know why and what this message mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need to specify `tempdb` when talking about `#table` - a temporary table is *already* in `tempdb`. I agree that the message is confusing, but it isn't actually an *error* - it is just a message (`PRINT`) telling you that you did something wrong. You actually get that message *regardless* of whether it exists or not; for example:

```
-- drop when doesn't exist
drop table if exists tempdb..#foo

go

-- drop when does exist
create table #foo (id int)
drop table if exists tempdb..#foo
```

outputs the message *twice*:

```
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
```

So: just use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table;
```

This is what it wants you to do.

Comment: Very nice, we do not need to point to the `tempdb` anymore as in the `OBJECT_ID` function.

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table;` it throws error. **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.**

Comment: @gotqn indeed; it is only `OBJECT_ID` that needs that, and we aren't using `OBJECT_ID` here

Comment: @DineshDB on what server version? I've literally *just run it* (on 2016) - it works fine

Comment: @DineshDB `drop if exists` can be used with `SQL Server 2016` - https://www.google.bg/search?q=tsql+drop+if+exists&oq=tsql+drop+if+exists&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4666j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Oh sorry @MarcGravell, I'm using 2014 only

Comment: What happen with me and it could help others was, I had a query where I specified the full path of the table,i.e., for instance: 

select * 
from <database>.dbo.tableXpto

But later on I decided to use a temporary table and I did this:

select * 
from <database>.dbo.#Temp

And that message started to appear. I just had to do this:

select * 
from #Temp

No need to have "<database>.dbo." previous to the temporary table.